# Find all dependencies of a ROS 2 workspace for a source build

Tags: ros2, rosdep, debian, ament

I have a project where I use a proprietary library to exchange data with a PLC, therefore I have to use debian as operating system. As a consequence, I have to build the ROS distro from source.

Instead of using a [full .repos file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/humble/ros2.repos) and add COLCON_IGNORES for unwanted packages:
Is there a possibility to get the package names of all ROS dependencies recursively up to the core ROS packages, starting from my workspace? I could then use this list to manually create a .repos file by looking for the correct git repositories.

The direct dependencies can be listed with

```
grep -RhI -e "^ *<exec_depend>" -e "^ *<build_depend>"  -e "^ *<run_depend>" ~/catkin_ws/src | sed -e "s/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/" | sort | uniq
```

from [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/251732/how-can-generate-a-list-of-dependencies-from-the-src-folder-of-a-workspace/), but their respective dependencies have to be searched iteratively after pulling the sources.

Or is there any smarter way to create a .repos file, or a different approach if there are no released ROS binaries for the target system?

Answer (score 2):

I'm in a similar situation. I haven't found a comprehensive way to quickly generate a .repos file from my dependencies for example, but `colcon graph` definitely helped me get an overview of what packages depend on what. More documentation here: https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/verb/graph.html

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `colcon graph`. But maybe someone comes up with a direct solution..